# Iterating through labels

Tags: objective-c

I have a bunch of labels starting from

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber0;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber5;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber6;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber7;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber8;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber9;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber10;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber11;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber12;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber13;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber14;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber15;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber16;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber17;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber18;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber19;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber20;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber21;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber22;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNumber23;
```

And these are aimed to be passed through on an iteration basis in a for loop here;

```
        for (int d = 0; d < [lastNumbers count]; d++) {
            int value = [[lastNumbers objectAtIndex:d] intValue];
            if ([red containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]])
            {
                self.lastNumber0.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
                self.lastNumber0.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
                self.lastNumber0.textColor  = [UIColor redColor];
            }
            if ([black containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]])
            {
                self.lastNumber0.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
                self.lastNumber0.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
                self.lastNumber0.textColor  = [UIColor blackColor];
            }
            if ([green containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]])
            {
                self.lastNumber0.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
                self.lastNumber0.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                self.lastNumber0.textColor  = [UIColor greenColor];
            }
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this makes sense, where `self.lastNumber0.text` would be replaced with a programtical `self.lastNumber[d].text` <-- and I know that will not work, but that's what I'm trying to achieve, I tried this

```
   NSString *labelName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lastNumber%i", d];
```

But cannot figure out how to do `self.labelName.text` = blah...

Thanks for reading and if you need any more information just ask. Thanks!

ANSWER

```
int yInc = 310;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    label[i] = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(460, yInc, 100, 10)];
    label[i].font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
    label[i].backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.3];
    [self.view addSubview:label[i]];
    yInc = yInc - 10;
}

            for (int d = 0; d < 32; d++) {
                int value = [[lastNumbers objectAtIndex:d] intValue];
                if ([red containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]])
                {
                    label[d].text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
                    label[d].textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
                    label[d].textColor = [UIColor redColor];
                }
                if ([black containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]])
                {
                    label[d].text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
                    label[d].textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
                    label[d].textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                }
                if ([green containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]])
                {
                    label[d].text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
                    label[d].textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                    label[d].textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: lastNumber23 variable screams that something is seriously wrong in your app architecture...

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve I cannot figure to achieve with only one label. So to get it to work for the small purpose it serves as well as learning how to iterate through property names is worth it right now. But thanks for your input.

Comment: You cannot "iterate through property names."

Comment: @matt I realised that, and hence my question. I tried to provide as much information of what I am trying to achieve, so was looked for advice on how to achieve it. Not "The way you've said it can't be done, can't be done.'

Comment: @user3891942 No, clearly you _didn't_ realize that, since you explicitly said in your previous comment that one of your goals was "learning how to iterate through property names". I'm responding to that, by saying there is no such thing to learn.

Comment: @matt perhaps my wording would give your point validity. But my aim was to achieve what I was asking, and it can be achieved just not iterating through property names. As with most things I've learned in programming, there's always a way to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making a bunch of IBOutlets to the individual labels, make a single IBOutletCollection to all of them. Now the labels are the elements of an array and you can just cycle through that array.

Comment: Ah, I really don't know why I didn't think of that.. :| Thanks for your answer.